# End-2-end шифрование в web

Tags: php, javascript, шифрование

Разбираюсь с шифрованием (end-2-end). Не могу понять где хранить ключи или ключ. Нашел библиотеку https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-08-19-end-to-end-encryption.html

но там сказано, что ключ нужно хранить в сессии, что не безопасно(я так думаю).

Можно ли хранить вообще реализовать end-to-end в web приложении?
Если можно то где хранить ключи?

Comment: а почему сессии не безопасны? с чего вы это взяли?

Comment: ну потому что разработчик имеет доступ к сессии и может от туда взять ключ, или я не прав?

Comment: Имеется ввиду что ключи должны быть только у клиентов, минуя сервер?

Comment: да, хотелось бы так)

Comment: Ой, понятно. Крч парень щас `телеграм №2` сделает, потом из-за него опять РКН половину интернета(ипов) заблокирует. Не помогайте парню, спасем интернет.

Comment: ахаха, я просто хочу разобраться где хранить ключи))